# HQL 42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, postgresql, hql, npgsql

HQL query against a PostgreSQL database:

```
var checkLines = _Session.CreateQuery(
    @"select lines from FinancialStatement statement
        inner join fetch statement.FinancialStatementLines lines
    where statement.FinancialStatementId = :statementId
        and lines.TransactionType = :transactionType
        and length(lines.CheckNumber) > 0")
    .SetParameter("statementId", statement.FinancialStatementId)
    .SetParameter("transactionType", TransactionTypes.Debit)
    .List<FinancialStatementLine>();
```

The query looks OK to me, but I am a newbie at HQL.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I'm assuming the problem is with the HQL, please let me know if you think I need to look elsewhere.

**THE PLOT THICKENS**

Upon examining the query created by the above HQL, I discover it looks like this:

```
select 
    financials1_.LineId as LineId14_, 
    financials1_.FinancialStatementId as Financia2_14_, 
    financials1_.APPaymentID as APPaymen3_14_, 
    financials1_.EffectiveDate as Effectiv4_14_, 
    financials1_.Amount as Amount14_, 
    financials1_.TransactionType as Transact6_14_, 
    financials1_.CheckNumber as CheckNum7_14_, 
    financials1_.Description as Descript8_14_, 
    financials1_.VendorDescription as VendorDe9_14_, 
    financials1_.FinancialStatementId as Financia2_, 
    financials1_.LineId as LineId 
from 
    FinancialStatements financials0_ 
where 
    financials0_.FinancialStatementId=:p0 
    and financials1_.TransactionType=:p1 
    and length(financials1_.CheckNumber)>0
```

...now, WTF? The `select` clause aliases don't exist in the `from` clause, which explains the error, but not, of course, why the error exists.

How can I work around this?

Comment: But what is the full error and stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the deal:  apparently when using HQL, to generate the right query, you need to have the object type you are trying to get as the first part of the query, for example:

```
var paymentLines = _Session.CreateQuery(
    @"select lines from FinancialStatementLine lines
        inner join fetch lines.Statement statement
    where statement.FinancialStatementId = :statementId
        and lines.TransactionType = :transactionType")
    .SetParameter("statementId", statement.FinancialStatementId)
    .SetParameter("transactionType", TransactionTypes.Debit)
    .List<FinancialStatementLine>();
```

This works, where the other query doesn't.  In SQL, the order of the joins doesn't matter so much; in HQL, it seems quite important.